# WPF UserControl (0, 0) is a center, not top-left point

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl in WPF, that has only a border and no other elements. It's height, width, and Background are set in style and it's default style is set in XAML, and than changed programmatically depending on users action.
My problem is that I need to draw two rectangles on it and when I set the start location of the first to be (0/0) on the control, it's being drawn in the center of the control instead. What can cause this behavior?

My Style here:

```xml
    <Style x:Key="MyControl_1" TargetType="{x:Type thermovision_views:TristableSwitch}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyControl_Default}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="/Images/1.png"/>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/2.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="116" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="116" />
            <Setter Property="mynamespace:MyControl.Value" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    
    <Style x:Key="MyControl_Default" TargetType="{x:Type mynamespace:MyControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Default}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type mynamespace:MyControl}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    
    <Style x:Key="Default" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    </Style>
```

My control XAML:

```xml
    <UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"             
                 prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
        <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="Placeholder" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Part of my control cs that create and draws the rectangles:

```cs
    private void SetupTouchRegions() {
                int x = (int)Canvas.GetLeft(this); //Returns inappropriate value like -27890
                int y = (int)Canvas.GetTop(this); //Returns inappropriate value like -27890
                TouchRegionUp = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)Width, TouchRegionVerticalOffset);
                TouchRegionDown = new Rectangle(0, (int)Height - TouchRegionVerticalOffset, (int)Width, TouchRegionVerticalOffset);
            }
    
    private void DrawTouchRegionsBorders() {
                var container = new Canvas();
                var touchRegionUp = TypeConverter.Rectangle(TouchRegionUp);
                var touchRegionDown = TypeConverter.Rectangle(TouchRegionDown);
    
                //TouchRegionUp
                Canvas.SetLeft(touchRegionUp, TouchRegionUp.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(touchRegionUp, TouchRegionUp.Y);
                touchRegionUp.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
                touchRegionUp.StrokeThickness = 2;
    
                //TouchRegionDown
                Canvas.SetLeft(touchRegionDown, TouchRegionDown.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(touchRegionDown, TouchRegionDown.Y);
                touchRegionDown.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
                touchRegionDown.StrokeThickness = 2;
    
                //Add container element to Control
                container.Children.Add(touchRegionUp);
                container.Children.Add(touchRegionDown);
                this.Content = container;
            }
```

Defined type aliases:

```cs
    global using Rectangle = System.Drawing.Rectangle;
    global using WpfRectangle = System.Windows.Rect;
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What class is that Rectangle? The WPF Rectangle does not have a constructor that takes four arguments.

Comment: @Clemens I'm using type aliases and forgot to provide it. I'll update the post to provide this info.

Comment: System.Drawing.Rectangle is WinForms, not WPF. Use System.Windows.Rect instead.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks I've changed to System.Windows.Rect, but it doesn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overcome this problem by using different approach.
I've used Dock Panel:

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Rectangle x:Name="UpperRectangle" 
                       Height="50" 
                       Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                       DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                       Opacity="{Binding TouchRegionOpacity}"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="LowerRectangle" 
                       Height="50" 
                       Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                       DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                       Opacity="{Binding TouchRegionOpacity}"/>
        </DockPanel>
```